# Python POST Request x-www-form-urlencoded received error "Object of type Response is not JSON serializable"

Tags: python, flask, post, request, x-www-form-urlencoded

i'm having an issue while write codes for consume another API using Python + Flask + Requests.
their API using PHP with x-www-form-urlencoded instead of RAW JSON, here is my code :

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api/test/getinfo', methods=['POST'])
def get_house_info():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            payloads = {'no_house':'001234123', 'cd_agent' : '01', 'nm_agent' : 'ABC'}          
            response_data = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, data=payloads)
            return response_data
        except Exception as e:
            return(str(e))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

after that i run this flask and tried to call this endpoint using postman
but i received error **Object of type Response is not JSON serializable** is there something wrong in my codes ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `json.dumps()` for `payloads`

python dictionary and json is not the same, refer to its usage here:

> Note: Keys in key/value pairs of JSON are always of the type str. When a dictionary is converted into JSON, all the keys of the dictionary are coerced to strings. As a result of this, if a dictionary is converted into JSON and then back into a dictionary, the dictionary may not equal the original one. That is, loads(dumps(x)) != x if x has non-string keys. [source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

---

From python to json : `json.dumps(x)`

From json to python : `json.loads(x)`

Comment: hi reema, thx for your reply..i tried that solution and still got same error "Object of type Response is not JSON serializable" from postman

Comment: @user15167308 apply it on your error too. the `e` is another object to convert. or access the data of that object that can be converted to string, e.g. : e.message